# MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion on every request

Tags: entity-framework

To make deployment a 1-click process, I am using the following code:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
        : base("MyDBContext")
    {            
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext, Configuration>());
    }

    public DbSet..
}

public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
}
```

I may add a seed method in the future.

In terms of performance, would it be significantly better to call this initializer on Application_Start or will EF be smart enough to know that nothing has changed?

Apart from losing the ability to view the migration, and possible performance issues, is this a bad idea?